# How to make reporting section of site database independent

Tags: java, spring, jpa

I need to build a reporting section of my site that consists of some decently complicated queries including things like UNION, GROUP_CONCAT, etc.  JPA integration with my entities has maintained database independence so far.  Currently the system uses MsSQL, but we want to be sure later we can switch to Postgres or MySQL if needed.

What's a good approach to take with these reports so that without too much work I can make it work on MySQL or Postgres?

The site also uses Spring

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I see it, your question is more or less "how can I make use of vendor specific features without becoming tied to that vendor?".

This result in not an easy answer; probably the most flexible would be stick to JPA and suck up the performance hit.

Other possibilities:

- Define the reports as a component that publish a set of interfaces. Use CDI to inject the implementation related to your DB of choice
- A variation of above, setup your own DAO interfaces for data access. Like another ORM framework that, being more specific, can have better performance. Build reports on top of that.
- If your bussiness allows for it, chose a RDBM to work with for reports. During night time (maybe even on demand, if there is not too much data), dump your production database into it.

Answer (score 0):

The best option is to use [data access objects](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_access_object), one per database, each conforming to a common interface. Any client code can use the common DAO interface without needing to know about the underlying database.

With Spring it is easy to swap between the DAO implementation classes as a configuration option, e.g. if you have a `CustomerDao` interface that has Oracle and DB2 implementations, then use either:

```
<bean id="customerDao" class="my.package.customer.OracleCustomerDao"/>
```

or

```
<bean id="customerDao" class="my.package.customer.Db2CustomerDao"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want your SQL to work across multiple databases, then here's a plan you can follow:

1. Test your SQL across multiple databases

To get portability, you need to write portable SQL. The only way to ensure that your SQL is portable is to check it for portability.

If you stick to using standard SQL, then this should be fairly straightforward; you won't be able to use database-specific features, but there is a huge amount you can do without them (they're mostly syntactic sugar, or for stepping outside the relational model, which you hopefully won't need to do). If you've already strayed into using nonstandard SQL, then it may be very hard to get the point where you can do this, but if if you start off working in a disciplined way, i would be optimistic about your ability to stick to standards.

If you're working on SQL Server, the  PostgreSQL would be a good choice for a second database to test against, as it's free, easy to set up, and very capable.